# Select element based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I have the following html and I am trying to add a class to it via the data attribute:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide" data-child-field="child_has_jacket">
</p>
```

Using jquery I've tried :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
       $('.form-row [data-child-field='child_has_jacket']').addClass("selected");
  });
```

Doesnt work. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `$('.form-row[data-child-field=child_has_jacket]').addClass("selected");`. Check space is removed after `.form-row` other wise it will start searching for child element with that data attribute.
2. Missing `;` in CSS around `height` and `display`

Working snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('.form-row[data-child-field=child_has_jacket]').addClass("selected");
});

/*Other working snippets
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('.form-row[data-child-field="child_has_jacket"]').addClass("selected");
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $(".form-row[data-child-field='child_has_jacket']").addClass("selected");
});*/
```

```css
.form-row.selected {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide" data-child-field="child_has_jacket">
</p>
```

Other working snippets:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('.form-row[data-child-field="child_has_jacket"]').addClass("selected");
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $(".form-row[data-child-field='child_has_jacket']").addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error , replace the `'` by `"`  in the data atribute class selector `data-child-field="child_has_jacket"` , also

attribute selector should have no space with class , otherwise it will search for child element with data attribute

it should be like :

```
$('.form-row[data-child-field="child_has_jacket"]')
```

See snippet :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
       $('.form-row[data-child-field="child_has_jacket"]').addClass("selected").html("selected class added");
  });
```

```css
.form-row.selected {
  border:1px solid black;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide" data-child-field="child_has_jacket">
</p>
```